# Basic Logarithm question - I can't get both answers from quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Here's the Question :

If  $xy$ = $64$ and $\log_x y + \log_y x = \frac{5}{2}$, find $x$ and $y$

---

I can get this to

$$log_x y + \frac{1}{\log_x y} \frac{5}{2}$$

let $\log_x y = N$

$$N + \frac{1}{N} =  \frac{5}{2}$$

Multiply by 2

$$2N + \frac{2}{N} =  5$$

Multiply by N

$$2N^2 + 2 =  5N$$

$$2N^2 - 5N + 2 = 0$$

$$(2N - 1)(N - 2)$$

Giving : 
$$N = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$N = 2$$

Therefore :

$$\log_x y = \frac{1}{2} $$

$$\log_x y = 2$$

Giving

$$x^2 = y$$

$$x^{\frac{1}{2}} = y$$

Part of the original question :

$$xy = 64$$

As $x^2 = y$

$$x * x * x = 64$$

$$x^3 = 64$$

Therefore:
$$x = 4$$
$$y = 16$$

---

I can't seem to solve for $y = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ though

Solving for $x^{\frac{1}{2}} = y$

$$x^{\frac{1}{2}} * x^{\frac{1}{2}} = 64$$

$$x^{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}} = 64$$
$$x= 64$$

$$xy= 64$$

$$64y= 64$$
Therefore

$$x = 64$$

$$y = 1$$

This is wrong though.

---

Answer :

$$(4,16) or (16,4)$$

I don't see how they got the second part. The first part makes sense but I'm not able to solve for $y = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Noticing the symmetry under a switch of x and y in the original question should lead to the conclusion of the second answer.

Comment: Hint. The original problem is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, so if $(4,16)$ is a solution then ...

Comment: You made a mistake in your algebra. You wrote $x^{\frac{1}{2}}\times x^{\frac{1}{2}} = 64$, but it's actually $x\times x^{\frac{1}{2}} = 64$

Comment: @user222031 you're right, thankyou :)

Comment: @Rammus thanks. I thought that it made sense for them to be inverted, but I was fumbling getting there algebraically. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$y=x^{1/2}$$ and $$xy=64$$ then $$x^{3/2}=64 = 2^6$$ so  $$x=2^{6\times 2/3} = 2^4 =16$$ and $$y=16^{1/2}=4.$$

Comment: thanks, I made the mistake with $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ before. I'm not too sure about the step
that follows ``so'' though,$x = 2^{6x\frac{2}{3}} = 2^4 = 16$. I'm a bit uncertain about 
how the exponent was shifted from the $x$ to the $2$ in this case. I can see that $4^2 = 2^4$ and that $4 = 2^{\frac{4}{2}}$ (that might be a bad example...) I'm just not seeing 
how the exponent from the $x$ term is shifted to the $2$. Cheers !

Comment: If $x^{3/2}=2^6$ then $\left(x^{3/2}\right)^{2/3}=\left(2^6\right)^{2/3}$, i.e. $x ^{3/2 \, \times \,2/3} = 2^{6  \, \times \,2/3}$ which means $x=2^4$ using$ \left(y^a\right)^b =  y^{ab}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log_x(y)+\log_y(x)=\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(x)}+\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(y)}=\frac{\ln^2(x)+\ln^2(y)}{\ln(x)\ln(y)}=\frac{(\ln(x)+\ln(y))^2}{\ln(x)\ln(y)}-2=\frac{\ln^2(xy)}{\ln(x)\ln(y)}-2$$
Then if $xy=64$,

$$\log_x(y)+\log_y(x)=\frac{5}{2}\implies \frac{\ln^2(64)}{\ln(x)\ln(y)}=\frac{9}{2}\implies \frac{2\ln^2(64)}{9}=\ln(x)\ln(y)\underset{xy=64}{=}\ln(x)\ln(\frac{64}{x})=-\ln^2(x)+\ln(x)\ln(64)$$

and thus, if you set $X=\ln(x)$ you get 
$$X^2-\ln(64)X+\frac{2\ln^2(64)}{9}=0.$$

$$\Delta =\ln^2(64)-\frac{8}{9}\ln^2(64)=\frac{1}{9}\ln^2(64)$$

Therefore $$X=\frac{\ln(64)\pm\frac{1}{3}\ln(64)}{2}$$
and thus $X=\frac{1}{3}\ln(64)=\ln(\sqrt[3]{64})=\ln(4)$ ou $X=\frac{2}{3}\ln(64)=\ln(\sqrt[3]{64^2})=\ln(16).$

Therefore $x=4$ and $y=16$ or $x=16$ and $y=4$. Finally, we conclude that $(x,y)=(4,16)$ or $(x,y)=(16,4)$.

Comment: thanks! I'm not really following this part :

$\frac{\ln^2(x)+\ln^2(y)}{\ln(x)\ln(y)}=\frac{(\ln(x)+\ln(y))^2}{\ln(x)\ln(y)}-2=\frac{\ln^2(xy)}{\ln(x)\ln(y)}-2$

Where does the $-2$ come from there?

Comment: Because $$\ln^2(x)+\ln^2(y)=\underbrace{\ln^2(x)+2\ln(x)\ln(y)+\ln^2(y)}_{=(\ln(x)+\ln(y))^2}-2\ln(x)\ln(y)$$Is it right ? :-)

Comment: I'm sure it's right, bit dense for me to follow though I'm afraid. thanks though :)